# I have changed prototype on Object, then jQuery will out put same attr in HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have changed prototype from Object to make me easy on type-checking

like this:

```
Object.prototype.getClass = function(){return this.constructor.name;};
```

but the problem is, when I use jQuery to set attr like this:

```
$('<video>').attr({width:1280,heigth:720}).appendTo(document.body)
```

then it will output like this:

```
<video width="1280" height="720" getClass="HTMLVideoElement"></video>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest that prototyping the Object base class is not a good idea - for the reason you're seeing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clearly knew do something in javascript like this was not a good idea.

But if someone need the solution, here is:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'getClass', {

  enumerable: false,

  value: function(){
    getClass = function(){return this.constructor.name;
  }

});
```

But it will happend many problem when you add a function to `Object.prototype`.

Because all lib will extend it, it will make many trouble.